# Spark Streaming from a folder in AWS s3 - PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a folder "input" in aws 3. I want to stream the new files created in that folder. I am using this code:

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
rdd = ssc.textFileStream("s3n://dynamodbstream607/input/*")
```

But it throws an error saying that input/* doesnot exist.
How do i get spark to stream from a folder in S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/12752) it will be available in 2.0.